# Changing react barcode format

Tags: reactjs, barcode

I am currently using the react-barcode package. It is currently using the `format="CODE128"` format, I needed to change it to use the Code 39 Barcode Font. How to I import the font to my react project and use it in the react-barcode component. If its not possible is there any other components I can use to achieve this.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Barcode from 'react-barcode';

 class Posts extends Component { 
     render () {
         return (
           <div>
               <Barcode value="http://github.com/kciter" />
           </div>
         );
     }
 }

 export default (Posts);
```

Display of the
[code128 barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQEu1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-barcode doesn't use a barcode font at all.

You can just, following the docs, set `format="CODE39"`.

```
<Barcode value="123456" format="CODE39" />
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, will read through the docs aswell.